Third Party Libraries are broken if Angular project work with Micro Frontend architecture
If the Angular project architecture uses Micro Frontend (Host and MFEs), and you run the nmp commands to install echarts, all echarts links will show as broken while building any project.
Sample of a generated error:
[ERROR] File 'node_modules/echarts/types/dist/charts.d.ts' is missing from the TypeScript compilation. [plugin angular-compiler]
I have tried several solutions and nothing works, such as adding path of echarts in tsconfig.app.ts and and also in angular.js with no success.

The file 'node_modules/echarts/types/dist/charts.d.ts' is really at this path !

After numerous attempts and repeated searches, I finally discovered the solution:
In the package.json file, I resolved the issue by moving the echarts and ngx-echarts packages from the standard dependencies section to a new peerDependencies section at the end of the file, as shown below:
"peerDependencies": {
   "echarts": "^5.5.1",
   "ngx-echarts": "^18.0.0"
}

With this change, everything started working perfectly.
